Firefox 128 snap Telemetry privacy problem
I have all telemetry disabled in Firefox settings.
Settings > Firefox Data Collection and Use: all unchecked.

Still I see JS running on searchpages with binding events to the input field, like:
sync event => {
  let start = Cu.now();
  if (condition(event)) {
    callback({
      action,
      target
    });
  }
  ChromeUtils.addProfilerMarker(
    "SearchSERPTelemetryChild._eventCallback",
    start,
    "Call cached function before callback."
  );
}

Seems to be a part of Firefox Telemetry, but I don't want that running, and of course it should not run when all telemetry is disabled.
Firefox 128 Ubuntu 22.04
What is going on? How do I disable this code?
BTW I don't see this with Firefox Beta 129 (deb)

You may want to try the Firefox support site.
